# Button in Android with two sets of text

Tags: android, text, button

does anybody know how can I se the text of a Button in Android to hold some text aligned to the left, and another to the right?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do a custom button.

It's really easy just do something like:

```
<LinearLayout... android:orientation="horizontal" android:onClick="clickButtonMethod" android:clickable="true">

<TextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Align left" android:gravity="left">

<TextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Align right" android:gravity="right">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ImageView or ImageButton instead of Button.

Answer (score 0):

Give the space between these text as you want the width of that button is WRAP_CONTENT.